# What am I doing wrong with the CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to import three social media icons in to my website. The size of the icons are not getting right, what am i doing wrong here? This is the html code:

Gonna make the question easier for you to understand since this is something im trying to add at the end of my project right now.

```
    <body>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
       --More code beneath--
```

So im putting the icons in a already existing section and div since i want the icons to be on top of the page.

Then you have the css for the section and div:

```
    section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 100px 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: white;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 61px 7px #5e849c40;
  padding: 50px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

And finally you have what im trying to import:

```
    ul {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  text-align:center;
  margin:10px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration:none;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #ddd, #fff);
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
  position: relative;
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  margin:10px 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration:none;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #ddd, #fff);
  transition: .5s;
}
```

I suppose there is something in the section or div('.container') that could be messing this up, just not able to see it after hours of trying already :'(

Comment: On the codepen link everything looks fine, do you want to change the icons size?

Comment: Did you import bootstrap?
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Also which version of fontawesome are you trying to use ? (you are not using similar class fa instead fab.

Comment: Yes, on the site im importing it from the facebook and other icons are centrally in the circle, but for me the stay in the top of the circle. Im using this link 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css', when i try with fab instead of fa i dont get the icons at all.

Comment: I just edited my first post trying to make it easier for you to see what im trying to do

Answer (score 1):

Instead of class `.fa`, try using class `.fab` and using this link: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css`

Reference: https://fontawesome.com/icons

```css
ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #ddd, #fff);
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
  position: relative;
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 6px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration:none;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #ddd, #fff);
  transition: .5s;
}


ul li a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  text-decoration:none;
}

ul li a .fab {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  display: block;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #fff, #ddd);
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: calc(60px - 12px);
  font-size:24px;
  color: #262626;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">

<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ah finally! Now i have the icons and hover effects exactly as i wanted! Thanks for that, one last problem now is that the icons ended up like behind the pictures im importing from pexels with an api, i want them on top of the screen, any ideas? Gonna try and adjust some but if u think of anything that would be nice, other wise thanks a lot! :D

Comment: Hey man! Thanks a lot but I figured it out at last, was some settings in the css I got wrong and after tweaking it a bit i finally got it to work! :D

Answer (score 1):

the `class="fa fa-facebook"` is used in the old version of fontawesome, if you want to use `class="fa fa-facebook"` you have to use this link below

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha256-eZrrJcwDc/3uDhsdt61sL2oOBY362qM3lon1gyExkL0=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

But if you want to use the newest link you should go to FontAwesome's site and copy the icon code.

Answer (score 0):

You are not linking the fonts.

```css
ul {
position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  text-align:center;
  margin:10px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration:none;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #ddd, #fff);
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
  position: relative;
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  margin:10px 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration:none;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #ddd, #fff);
  transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<!-- Font Awesome icons (free version)-->
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<section>
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```